# JavaFX, печать таблицы

Tags: java, javafx, print

Здравствуйте. Подскажите, как мне распечатать таблицу JavaFX(TableView)?
Пробовал читать JavaDoc, и, правда, ничего особо не понял.
Нужно вывести на печать текст перед таблицей, таблицу и текст после таблицы.
Помогите, пожалуйста.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Сделать скрин и распечатать его?

Comment: Нет, не скрин. Определенный текст перед таблицей, таблицу и текст после нее

Comment: Я к тому,чтобы сделать скриншот нужной части приложения и вывести на печать. В данном случае 2 текста и таблица